# Showing elapsed time in VS Code terminal

Tags: python, terminal, timer, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

When I was executing my python code with code-runner, it showed the result in the *"Output"* with the elapsed time.

```
[Done] exited with code=0 in 179.605 seconds
```

I switched to using the terminal and I no longer know how long my program took to execute.

I am aware that I can manually set a timer and print it.

But is there an option to do it in *.vscode/settings.json* ?

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
   "python": "$pythonPath $fullFileName",
   }
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true
```

Or any other way. I've seen it done like the picture below.

[image: VS Code terminal with execution time shown]

Answer (score 4):

Try `time python <your_python_file.py>` in the terminal.